# How to find eigenvector of given matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Is Lambda=4 is eigenvalue of
>
> $$
>  \left(
>         \begin{matrix}
>         3 & 0 & -1 \\
>         2 & 3 & 1 \\
>         -3 & 4 & 5 \\
>         \end{matrix}
> \right)
> $$
>   If so find one corresponding eigenvector.

I know how to determine if the given lambda value is eigenvalue. I just solve
$ (A-\lambda I)x=0$. But I'm not sure what approach to use in finding eigenvector of that matrix.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know a best way than an other to find eigenvector...

Comment: Set the determinant of the relevant matrix equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i row reduce the matrix $A - 4I$ i get $$\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0} $$ therefore an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $4$ is $$\pmatrix{1\\1\\-1}. $$

Comment: Thanks! But why is it -x3 as a common?Why not just x3?

Comment: @user3273345, any nonzero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. i just picked $x_3 = -1$ so that we can have $x_1 = x_2 = 1.$ had i picked $x_3 = 1,$ then $x_1 = x_2 = -1$